# Implementing and wrapping function composition in C++ for lazy evaluation

Tags: c++, functional-programming, template-meta-programming

Suppose I have a naive implementation of an `applicative`, which is a name I picked for sanity and not that I know anything about `Applicative` type class from other languages. Here goes the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct applicative {
    template <typename Fn>
    auto then(Fn f) const {
        return applicative<decltype(f(data_))>{f(data_)};
    } 

    template <typename Fn>
    auto and_last(Fn f) const {
        return f(data_);
    }
    T data_;
};

int main() {
    applicative<std::string>{"hello world"}
    .then([](std::string const& s) {return s.size() * 4; })
    .then([](int k) {return k - 2; })
    .and_last([](int k) { std::cout << k << "\n"; });
}
```

Now, this could be improved in many ways. Providing something like `make_applicative` for in-place construction, trying to eliminate redundant copies and moves if there are any etc. But from the time I saw our ability to compose functions in C++, I feel like something better is possible. Any compose implementation would work, so let's pick the one in this [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/c-function-composition) question. With it, we can say things like

```
auto f1 = [](std::pair<double,double> p) {return p.first + p.second; };
auto f2 = [](double x) {return std::make_pair(x, x + 1.0); };
auto f3 = [](double x, double y) {return x*y; };
auto g = compose(f1, f2, f3);

std::cout << g(2.0, 3.0) << std::endl;   //prints '13', evaluated as (2*3) + ((2*3)+1)
```

Pretty nice. Going back to my idea, I think this should make possible a rework of my `applicative` implementation in following way:

```
auto sf = applicative<std::string>{}
    .then([](std::string const& s) {return s.size() * 4; })
    .then([](int k) {return k - 2; });

    std::cout << sf.eval_with("hello world"); << "\n";
```

As you can see, this is sort-of lazy evaluated and we only supply value when we need it, with `eval_with`. I've been thinking about how to implement this new version for one hour now and I have no idea where to store operations and composed functions, what to make of `applicative` template parameter like we have here with `std::string` and many more problems. How would one implement something like this? Is it trivial as I initially hoped to be or does it require a lot of code? I really want this because I feel like this would buy me a lot by preventing a lot of argument passing on long chain of functions.

Edit: I am working on it a little more and turns out `compose` implementation I linked is not what I actually had in mind since we are still performing all the function calls in the chain and still passing arguments around. But you can answer assuming any `compose` function would work and choice of a better `compose` implementation would be a performance optimization. What I had in mind was more like following, taken from my example

```
applicative<std::string>{"hello world"}
    .then([](std::string const& s) {return s.size() * 4; })
    .then([](int k) {return k - 2; })
    .and_last([](int k) { std::cout << k << "\n"; });
```

Those `then` calls would result in a single function call equivalent to `(s.size() * 4) - 2` which could be evaluated with `eval_with`.

Comment: What did you have in mind? You are always going to have to call all the functions, either eagerly (first case), or lazily (second case)

Comment: Your target is equivalent to a curried `compose`

Comment: @Caleth given the `std::bind`, I think it won't be as efficient as I want if currying is involved?

Comment: you can take a look at boost::lambda and boost::yap first.

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct id
{
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(T t) const
    {
        return t;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Func = id>
struct applicative {
    applicative(Func f = Func())
        : _f(f)
    {
    }

    template <typename Fn>
    auto then(Fn f) const {
        auto composition = [=](T val) { return f(_f(val)); };
        return applicative<T, decltype(composition)>(composition);
    } 

    auto eval_with(T t)
    {
        return _f(t);
    }

    Func _f;
};

int main() {
    auto sf = applicative<std::string>{}
    .then([](std::string const& s) {return s.size() * 4; })
    .then([](int k) {return k - 2; });

    std::cout << sf.eval_with("hello world") << "\n"; 
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't bother about perfect forwarding, so everything is passed by value.

Comment: Pretty much, I had the idea of inventing an identity function but could not make it work. With some perfect forwarding, I can cut this down to one extra move to pass the argument from `eval_with` to first `then` call. Thanks. By any chance you also know if this thing corresponds to any category theoretic type class? Closish to  `Functor` maybe?